# Использование тега 0.0.0

Tags: git, версионирование, git-tag

Боевой продукт, должен начинатся с версии 0.0.0 или 1.0.0 ?

Есть ли ограничения в Semver на использование 0.0.0 версии тега ?

Comment: Странно, никогда не встречал версию 0.0.0

Comment: никто не запрещает же, вот хотелось бы узнать теперь, почему бы нет?)

Comment: Дока рекомендует начинать с 0.1.0 - https://semver.org/#how-should-i-deal-with-revisions-in-the-0yz-initial-development-phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Спецификация](https://semver.org/#spec-item-4)
ясно говорит, что версии типа `0.y.z` предназначены для
начала разработки:

> *Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything MAY
> change at any time. The public API SHOULD NOT be considered stable.*